# Selecting the row with max attributes from another entity

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to get an id (or *, whatever) from shelf, that contains the most books published by a publisher for this project I'm working on, but I can't get my head around getting the query right. I'm using plain SQL.

Below is the diagram of how my database is set up, simplified.
[image: Diagram of the database]
Edit: The entity_3 is supposed to be the publisher, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, but since you might get multiple shelves each with the same maximum number, it might return multiple shelf ids.  If that's not what you want, you can cut it to a single id in several ways, e.g. by doing a MIN() on the shelf_id.

```
select b.id_shelf
  from (select s.id_shelf,        
               count(*) as sp_count      
          from shelf s,       
               book b         
         where s.id_shelf = b.id_shelf
           and b.publisher = @publisher
         group by s.id_shelf
       ) b
 where b.sp_count = (select max(a.sp_count)
                       from (select s.id_shelf,       
                                    count(*) as sp_count      
                               from shelf s,          
                                    book b        
                              where s.id_shelf = b.id_shelf
                                and b.publisher = @publisher
                              group by s.id_shelf
                            ) a
                     ) b
```